# How to handle income tax for weird insurance claim scenario

Tags: united-states, income-tax, insurance

About 5 years ago, a dependent attended a treatment facility in another state. All of the insurance checks were sent to me and I forward them on, since the facility was out of network. We thought this was all over and done, and the facility has since closed its doors.

But, last summer, the insurance company notified me that there were several checks uncashed and it would go to unclaimed funds if we didn't figure out what to do with it.  Since then, they have sent me these checks, and the only option is to deal with it as income.

My question: how does the IRS view this scenario?  Is this straight-up income? Is there some way I can deduct part or all of it? (We did pay quite a bit of money before insurance kicked in.)

What key words can I use while trying to hunt down answers on my own?

Comment: Is this reimbursement for what you paid? Or you should have forwarded the payment to the provider?

Comment: @littleadv - The payment was forwarded, but the provider apparently didn't cash all of the checks.

Comment: then why is it income to you? The checks were in the provider's name?

Comment: @littleadv Because the insurance company had to pay someone, and the facility is out of business. So, I got it.

Comment: I guess lucky you. The provider no longer exists but you got the money? Put it on misc income (line 8z of schedule 1).

Comment: @littleadv: Thanks!

Comment: In theory, the treatment facility's bankruptcy trustee could realize that somebody still owes them money and go after the insurance company, which would point at you, and you'd have to pay up. So don't spend the money just yet.